# ASP.NET MVC Session gets reset after using RedirectToAction within iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC application (say, App_A) and another ASP.NET application (say, App_B). App_B has an iframe that loads App_A within it.

The code on App_B looks something like this:
`iframe.Attributes["src"] = frameURL;`
where frameURL is a variable containing a link to App_A.

When the iframe loads the URL and the `index()` method on App_A gets invoked, I'm setting a value in session `Session["CartID"] = 373895` and I'm using `RedirectToAction("Shipping")`. But within the `Shipping()` action method, the session seems to be `null`. The code that sets the session variable and calls `RedirectToAction()` are within the iframe.

**A similar issue that I encountered previously on Safari browser:**

This has been working fine for the past 2 years without any issues. Previously, I was only having CORS issue on Safari browser. Since the websites on the parent window and the iframe were from different domains, I was not able to retain session values within iframe after redirection as it was getting reset. To fix this on Safari, I had to load the iframe site (App_A) on the parent window, set a cookie and then redirect back to the parent website and load App_A within iframe again. This allowed me to retain session values even after redirection. Now that I have a similar issue on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge, I tried the same fix that worked for Safari (as described above) but I'm still unable to retain session values on Chrome and other browsers.

**Some debug information:**

I tried debugging this and I added `Session_Start()` method to the `Global.asax` file and it gets hit twice, once before and once after calling `RedirectToAction("Shipping")`. The `SessionID` is also different before and after calling `RedirectToAction("Shipping")`.

This issue occurs only when I run App_A from my local machine. When I try it in our production site, it works fine without any issues. Also, when I load App_A on the parent window, it retains session values without any issues. That is, on App_B I replaced `storefrontiframe.Attributes["src"] = frameURL;` with `Response.Redirect(frameURL);` and when App_A gets loaded on a new window, the session values are being retained without any issues.

I'm not sure why my session values are being cleared all of a sudden after calling `RedirectToAction()`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We can understand your frustration, but if you want to get some help, you should be more specific. How did you fix the problem with Safari? What was the problem on there? Focus on the problem. It will better to say: "I have this problem on this setup... I have tried this much..."

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego Sorry, maybe I should have explained the Safari issue better. I was facing CORS issue with Safari. Since the website on the parent window and the iframe were from different domains, I was not able to retain session values after redirection as it was getting reset. To fix this on Safari, I had to load the iframe site (App_A) on the parent window, set a cookie and then redirect back to the parent website and load App_A within iframe again. This allowed me to retain session values even after redirection. I tried the same for Chrome now, but my session values are getting reset.

Comment: So, please, introduce it in your original post.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. I've updated my original post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by adding a "cookieSameSite" attribute with "None" as value to the sessionState node in the Web.config. Something like this:

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" timeout="60" />
```

Comment: Works for me too. Would be curious to know why this resolves the issue

Comment: @Javier Molina, unfortunately it does not solve problem for Chrome incognito mode.

Comment: @Rahul, it seems that Chrome started to block third-party cookies by default in Incognito mode, so I'm afraid there's nothing we can do about it. See this: https://blog.google/products/chrome/more-intuitive-privacy-and-security-controls-chrome