# Session is null within iFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I am having a strange issues with iFrame. We are trying to use an Asp.net Website with Session inside iframe, as below:

We are always getting Session null exception within iFrame.

How to resolve this? Can you please help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="Source URL with Session Handling" width="100%" height="400">
  <p>Your browser does not support if`enter code here`rames.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look in this post. worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530589/asp-net-mvc-session-gets-reset-after-using-redirecttoaction-within-iframe

Comment: You can take a look if your problem still not resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925345/session-cookies-are-resetting-to-blank-in-asp-net-mvc-application-in-an-iframe/63958289#63958289