# Session/Cookies are resetting to blank in Asp.Net MVC application in an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iframe, session-cookies

After updating the chrome to 80 (Version 80.0.3987.149 (64-bit)) recently and clearing cookies of the browser we are seeing below issue in our ASP.Net MVC application.

Session/Cookies are resetting to blank when redirecting to other page. Application is embedded in a iFrame.

I have tried setting Same site to "None" in web.config in below ways but none of them worked -

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" timeout="60" />

<httpCookies sameSite="None" />
```

Also installed URL rewrite to override set cookie on IIS -

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="AddSameSiteCookieFlag">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^(.*)(CFID|CFTOKEN|JSESSIONID|ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0};SameSite=None" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Any help please...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and after doing a lot of research. It is solved by adding a `requireSSL` attribute in `<sessionState>`

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true"  />
```